# bat file to move parent folder ONLY containing PDFs into a new location and then delete the old parent folder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need the bat file to scan a directory and look at all of the subfolders. If a subfolder contains any PDFs then I need that parent folder to be moved into a new location and then deleted from the old location. Is this even possible via bat? Sorry i'm just starting with bat file writing.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but SU is not a script writing service so please give it your best shot and post if/where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is possible! Look if you have the chance to use powershell instead of batch (which is old). Powershell is more clearer to read than batch and most of the time you have access to powerfull tools.

Gonna give you a good help to start (if you use Powershell):

> Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\folder\to\start\scan" -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | select-object -unique directory | Foreach-Object{echo $_.Directory.FullName} | Out-String

After you just need to find a way to move your folders

Credits for this command:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126175/powershell-get-full-path-of-the-files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609884/delete-duplicate-string-with-powershell